# R : contingency table for two random variables

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I have two Beta variables *B1(8, 5)* and *B2(4, 7)* and I have generated 1000 samples for each of them.

If I had to use a 2-Way contingency table to test for the independence of the two sets of samples,

1) would it be appropriate to use a contingency table?

2) Any pointers to approach this correctly?

(I created a frequency table but all I see is this - all the samples of X arranged in rows, and all samples of Y arranged in columns , and 0 written across each cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta random variables can take any value continuously from 0 to 1.  So a simple contingency table does not make much sense.

You could look at the covariance, or a plot, or bin the data and then look at a contingency table.  Perhaps something like

```
> set.seed(1)
> B1 <- rbeta(1000, shape1=8, shape2=5)
> B2 <- rbeta(1000, shape1=4, shape2=7)
> cov(B1,B2)
[1] 0.0003400774
> plot (B1,B2)
> CT <- table(cut(B1,4), cut(B2,4))
> print(CT)

                (0.0518,0.246] (0.246,0.44] (0.44,0.635] (0.635,0.829]
  (0.214,0.401]             15           30           11             3
  (0.401,0.587]             77          173           83            12
  (0.587,0.774]            106          231          126            20
  (0.774,0.96]              25           54           30             4
> chisq.test(CT)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  CT 
X-squared = 2.4747, df = 9, p-value = 0.9816

Warning message:
In chisq.test(CT) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: This has been most helpful (entire code was not what I asked for but thanks for it , and the effort!) to understand why it wouldn't work and why covariance is better. Thanks!